# Adding constraints to permutations

Tags: python, permutation

I am trying to calculate all permutations with list = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6] adhering to some constraints.

- Position 0 must be > 3
- Position 3 + Position 5 < Position 4

With my current code I determining all permutations and iterations through each, applying the constraints.

```
import itertools

Used_permutations = []    
numbers = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]
all_permutations = list(itertools.permutations(numbers)) #Determine all permutations

for permutation in all_permutations:
    if permutation[0] > 3 and permutation[3] + permutation[5] < permutation[4]: #Constraints applied to permutations
        Used_permutations.append(permutation)  
        ####################################################
        ###   Apply calculations to current permutation ###
        ####################################################
```

The problem with this code is that I'm wasting time finding all possible permutations just to filter them out again. Can someone assist with a way to apply the constraints while permutations are determined so not all N! are determined?

Comment: Also position 0 being > 3 means position 0 **is** 4 since 4 is the only candidate that satisfies that.

Comment: Assuming that by positions 3, 4 and 5 you mean 2, 3, and 4, there are **only four** permutations that satisfy your conditions. `[4, 2, 0, 3, 1]`, `[4, 2, 1, 3, 0]`, `[4, 3, 0, 2, 1]` and `[4, 3, 1, 2, 0]`

Comment: Forgot these two `[4, 1, 0, 3, 2]` and `[4, 1, 2, 3, 0]`. So 6 in total

Comment: Sorry, copied wrong list. Edit to correct list.

Comment: @Pierre it's too late now mate..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of first creating a `list` of all the permutations and then adding some of those elements to a second list and discarding the rest (about 90% in this case), you can use a list comprehension to filter the permutations yielded by `itertools` as they are created.

```
>>> numbers = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]
>>> [p for p in itertools.permutations(numbers) if p[0] > 3 and p[3] + p[5] < p[4]]
[(4, 0, 1, 2, 6, 3, 5),
 (4, 0, 1, 3, 6, 2, 5),
 ... a few more ...
 (6, 5, 4, 1, 3, 0, 2),
 (6, 5, 4, 2, 3, 0, 1)]
>>> len(_)
516
```

If the checks become more complicated, you do not even have to use a list comprehension. You can do the same in a regular `for` loop with `if` conditions, the only difference being that you do not collect all the permutations in a `list` first, but iterate the generator directly:

```
all_permutations = itertools.permutations(numbers)  # no list(...)
for permutation in all_permutations:
    ...
```

Both approaches will still *generate* all the N! permutations, but most are immediately discarded and only the "right" ones are ever *stored* in the list.

---

If you do not even want to generate them, you will have to implement a custom recursive `permutations` algorithm and manually check whether e.g. for a given value for `p[3]` there can be any valid values for `p[5]` and so on. Something like this:

```
def manual_permutations(numbers, n=0, last=0, lastlast=0):
    if len(numbers) <= 1:
        yield tuple(numbers)
    else:
        for i, first in enumerate(numbers):
            # first constraint
            if n == 0 and first <= 3: continue
            # second constraint: 3 + 5 < 4 === 3 - 4 < -5 === 3 < 4 - 5
            # assuming numbers are ordered: rest[0] is min, rest[-1] is max
            rest = numbers[:i] + numbers[i+1:]
            if n == 3 and first >= rest[-1] - rest[0]: continue
            if n == 4 and last - first >= - rest[0]: continue
            if n == 5 and lastlast - last >= - first: continue
            # constraints okay, recurse
            for perm in manual_permutations(rest, n+1, first, last):
                yield (first,) + perm
```

This checks the two constraints while generating the permutations, so that if e.g. all the permutations starting with a number `<= 3` are not generated at all. The second check is a bit more complicated, and could probably be improved further (if we add a counter to the beginning of the function, we see that there are ~1200 recursive calls). Anyway, using IPython's `%timeit` we see that the "manual" approach with checks on the fly is still about three times *slower* than using `itertools`, so even improving the checks will probably not make it faster than that.<sup>*)</sup> Also, your own original loop is, in fact, not that much slower, either.

```
>>> %timeit original_loop(numbers)
1000 loops, best of 3: 736 µs per loop

>>> %timeit list(itertools_perms(numbers))
1000 loops, best of 3: 672 µs per loop

>>> %timeit list(manual_permutations(numbers))
100 loops, best of 3: 2.11 ms per loop
```

Of course, depending on the size of the input list and the constraints, the manual approach can present more or less of a saving, but can also be (much) more or less difficult to implement or to adapt to changing constraints. Personally, I'd still go with using `itertools.permutations` and a few simple, readable filters.

---

<sup>*)</sup> Update: In my previous edit, the manual approach came out faster; this was because I forgot to actually *consume* the generators returned by the two functions.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how i would implement a custom recursive permutation algorithm. I've been trying to add the the constraints directly into the recursion function but to no avail. I'm using a similar recursion function as Silveira Neto's solution in [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104420/how-to-generate-all-permutations-of-a-list-in-python).

Comment: @Pierre Please see my new edit. I made a mistake in my previous timing analysis and using `itertools` is actually faster.